# The Feynman Lectures on Physics Interference

Tags: waves, interference

From [The Feynman Lectures on Physics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html), Feynman states that:

> You will remember that the quantitative relationship between I1, I2, and I12 can be expressed in the following way: The instantaneous height of the water wave at the detector for the wave from hole 1 can be written as (the real part of) $h_1e^{iωt}$.

Where does $h_1e^{iωt}$ come from?

Answer (score 0):

Water waves are described by real numbers (i.e. the height of the water surface from the equilibrium position). So I guess you are expecting $h(t) = h \cos(\omega t)$ to be the describtion of the wave. It's very convenient (and standard), to encode this into a complex number. Note that $e^{i\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + i \sin(\omega t)$. Thus we can write $h(t) = \text{Re} \ he^{i\omega t}$.

In any calculation, we can work with complex numbers and take the real part at the very end. An example of how much easier working with complex numbers are, consider exactly what you are trying to calculate, what is the amplitude of $h_{12} = h_1(t) + h_2(t)$ (meaning what is the maximum of $h_{12}(t)$). Try doing it with complex numbers and with dealing with sines and cosines directly. See which way you'd prefer.

Also he uses 'You will remember' because it was discussed in earlier lectures. So you can also look it up in his lectures.